# Parse (Javascript): How to get an arbitrary subset of objects?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am using Facebook Parse with JavaScript with a Node/Express backend. I am looking to query my Parse database which contains over 900 objects of a particular class.

I am looking to arbitrarily split those 900 objects evenly 6 times. If it were an array, it would be something like `objects[0:150]`, `objects[151:300]`, etc...

How would I do this using Parse/JavaScript querying?

Thank you

Comment: parse.com's .find() method does return an array if I'm not mistaken, so why not just divide the array's length into 6 and use that as an index for your subset of the initial array? I'm not sure if I made myself clear

Comment: Please post the code you have tried to use so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not looking to query all 900 at once (which you won't be able to do if you get more than 1000 anyway), you can use the paging facilities in the API to do this work for you.

[limit](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#limit) and [skip](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html#skip) are the attributes of [Parse.Query](http://www.parse.com/docs/js/symbols/Parse.Query.html) that you might be interested in.

This will result in more queries to the server though, so if speed is your concern (or you have more than 1000 objects), then it's best to do this in code rather than via the query.